# Integration Authentication Error Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and Knime

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, knime

There are a number of older posts on integrating a database with Knime, however I haven’t found any discussions regarding the latest versions of Java, Knime, and SQL. I have spent days looking at forums here and on StackOverflow and elsewhere trying to connect to a database with Knime, however nothing has worked.

My computer configuration is as follows:
64 bit Operating System
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (64 bit version)
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17
Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.0 for SQL Server
KNIME 3.7.0 (64 bit version)
Java jre1.8.0_191

So far I’ve tried:
Downloading java versions into both Program Files\Java and Program Files (x86)\Java. Currently I have the java version that is stored in the Program Files directory and not in the (x86) directory.

Downloading and unzipping the ‘sqljdbc_7.0.0.0_enu’ JDBC 7.0 Driver. I also tried the JDBC 6.0 Driver, but that didn’t work.

putting sqljdbc_auth.dll in the C\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin and C\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib directories.

Enabling TCP/IP Port in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

configuring Knime’s Database Connector, Database Reader, and Microsoft SQL Server Connector nodes to the following settings:
Database driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Database URL: jdbc:sqlserver://(localhost); integratedSecurity=true;
Authentication: Checked ‘Use credentials’ (for Database Reader this feature is blocked out)

When I execute the Database Connector node I get the following error:
ERROR Database Connector 0:2 Execute failed: Could not create connection to database: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

When I execute the Database Reader node I get the following error:
ERROR Database Reader 0:1 Execute failed: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:4906d2f3-e3df-4016-a383-29840cb4dee2

When I execute the Microsoft SQL Server Connector I get the following error:
ERROR Microsoft SQL Server Connector 0:5 Execute failed: Could not create connection to database: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Comment: Do you have sqljdbc_auth.dll in a folder that is on the Windows PATH? The JDBC driver needs to be able to find the DLL so it can use integrated authentication.

Answer (score 1):

It [seems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017#Connectingintegrated) an extra setup step is required for the integrated authentication setup. I assume you are using KNIME with 64 bit JVM, so you should copy the `C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.4 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_<version>\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dll` to the `C:\Windows\System32` folder or add the following line to knime.ini (somewhere after the `-vmargs` line):

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.4 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_<version>\enu\auth\x64
```

(I assume `<version>` should be something fitting your JDBC driver set for KNIME. The path probably also requires further adjustments.)

I think the second option is preferred, so you can have different JDBC drivers, but it requires adjustments to knime.ini for all installation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's JDBC driver seems to prefer that sqljdbc_auth.dll be visible on the Windows `PATH` to make it available for trusted connections (Windows authentication) to a SQL Server instance. Ensure that the DLL is in a folder on the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error, here is how I resolve my issue of KNIME JDBC connection to MS SQLExpress with Windows authentication. I using the jTDS for Microsoft SQL Server that comes with KNIME.

Select the Microsoft SQL Server Connector Node and configure the node with the following settings:

- a) Hostname = localhost  (if running remote, replace with hostname or IP of remote server)
- b) Port = 1433           (default SQLserver port)
- c) Database Name = PracticeDB    (replace with your database name you wish to connect)
- d) Authentication: None/native authentication
- In the JDBC Parameters tab from the Microsoft SQL Server Connector, add the following:
  **integratedSecurity** for *Name* and the boolean value of **true**

KNIME Microsoft SQL Server Connector will generate the necessary JDBC connection string:

Database type: Microsoft SQL Server Connection: **URL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/PracticeDB" Driver: jTDS for Microsoft SQL Server (ID=jTDS for Microsoft SQL Server, Version=1.3.0)**